# Moment Generating Function of the Chi-Squared Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

The questions wants us to show that the MGF for the chi-squared distribution is equal to

[image: MGF]

I know that to show that I need to evaluate this integral.
I'm not sure where to begin to evaluate it.

$E[e^{aX}]=\frac{1}{2^{t/2}\Gamma(t/2)}\int_0^\infty x^{(t-2)/2}e^{-x/2}e^{ax}dx.$

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint:  The density of a $X \sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable (shape, scale) is given by $$f_X(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta}}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)}, \quad x > 0.$$  We know that this function integrates to $1$ over its support.  Can you rewrite the integrand you obtained in your expectation to fit such a gamma density for appropriate parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$?  What is the resulting constant factor that is missing?

Also, I think you should know that ${\rm E}[X^a]$ is not the MGF.  It's the $a^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $X$.

Comment: It seems to be a gamma~$(t/2,2)$. I'm confused on the what you mean by the resulting constant factor.

Comment: No, that's not correct.  Your $\alpha$ is correct, but $\beta$ is not $2$ because when you combine the terms $e^{-x/2} e^{ax} = e^{-x(1/2-a)}$, what must $\beta$ be?  Then your denominator is off, so you have to compensate with an appropriate constant factor of the form $\beta^\alpha$ in order for the integrand to be a gamma density.

Comment: So it's a gamma$(2-2a)$ which mean you would need to multiply the denominator by (1-a) and the numerator (1-a) then the gamma~$(t/2,2-2a)$ would evaluate to 1?

Comment: **NO**.  If $-x/\beta = -x(\frac{1}{2} - a)$, what is $\beta$?

Comment: Is it then $2-(1/a)?$

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you cannot do basic algebraic computations at your level, you need to go back and review that before you should ask questions about mathematical statistics.